Is the Kronecker Delta equivalent to this expression? $\delta_{ij} = \lfloor e^{-|i-j|} \rfloor$
I came across an expression and I’m curious about whether the following expression is valid:
$$\delta_{ij} = \lfloor e^{-|i-j|} \rfloor$$
Here's my reasoning for why they might be equivalent:
The standard Kronecker delta is typically defined as:
$$\delta_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } i = j, \\
0 & \text{if } i \neq j.
\end{cases}$$
Case 1: $i = j$
\begin{align}
    i = j: |i-j| &= |i-i| = 0 \\
    \text{Therefore,}\quad e^{-|i-j|} &= e^0 = 1 \\
    \text{Thus,}\quad \lfloor e^{-|i-j|} \rfloor &= \lfloor 1 \rfloor = 1
\end{align}
Case 2: $i \neq j$
\begin{align}
    i \neq j :|i-j| &> 0  \\
    \text{Therefore,}\quad 0 < e^{-|i-j|} &< 1 \\
    \text{Thus,}\quad \lfloor e^{-|i-j|} \rfloor &= 0
\end{align}
This seems to match the Kronecker delta definition.

Sure, it is not just equivalent, it is equal. You could use $(i-j)^2$ instead of $|i-j|.$ It's probably not very useful, though.

Don't worry too much. There are no issues with the details you provided. In fact, in mathematics, it is normal for a function to have many different representations. It is just seems to that a person has many clothes, but we need to choose clothes that are more suitable for different occasions. For example, in Euclidean space, $\delta_i^j = \langle e_i, e_j \rangle$. Anyway, one more affirmative answer, I think it will make you more sure of your idea.
